# Is there a way to access a mixin's private variable in the class using the mixin?

Tags: dart

In dart when creating a `mixin`, you can declare properties and methods like a class. When declaring a private property/method, it seems the inheriting class should also have access to this private member (see below for example).

Is there a way to access a `mixin`'s private variable in the class using the `mixin`?

If it's not possible, how can I declare a member in the `mixin` object but make it private in the inheriting class's interface.

`mixin.dart`

```dart
mixin A {
  String propertyOne = '1';

  // This property is not accessible to any inheriting class.
  int _privateProperty = 2;
}
```

`class.dart`

```dart
class B with A {
  String get mixinString => propertyOne;

  // This property is not accessible to the B class.
  int get mixinInt => _privateProperty;
}
```

Comment: Make a public getter in the mixin class that points to `privateProperty` that the inheriting class can access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A property being library private means that you can only express its *name* inside the same library. In any other library, the identifier `_privateProperty` is a different name, one private to that other library.

If you cannot declare both mixin and class in the same library, and you definitely need access to the property, then you can do any number of things to allow that.

- Make the property public and tell people not to use it except in subclasses. They still can if they want to.
- Make the property public and mark it [`@protected`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/meta/protected-constant.html), to have the analyzer tell people to not use it except in subclasses. They still can if they want to.
- Keep the property private and provide a separate method to access it:

  ```dart
  mixin A {
    // This property is not accessible to any inheriting class.
    int _privateProperty = 2;
    static int getPrivateProperty(A a) => a._privateProperty;
    static void setPrivateProperty(A a, int value) {
      a._privateProperty = value; 
    }
  }
  ```

  Anyone can still get to the property if they really want to, but they need to know that
  it comes from `A`.

Comment: Great explanation and alternative options. Thank you.